# Upsert with partial index: "there is no unique matching the ON CONFLICT specification"

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I'm using an `upsert` with a partial index. I know that I have to specify the predicate if I'm using a partial index but for some reason it can't find the index. I found a lot of similar posts but there it was usually a typo or a missing conditional in the `ON CONFLICT` clause. In my case I can't spot the issue.

The index looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_plays_on_user_id_and_episode_id ON db.plays USING btree (user_id, episode_id) WHERE (NOT ((client)::text = 'Web'::text))
```

I'm trying to do the following upsert but this doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO plays (client, user_id, scrobble_id, event_timestamp, episode_id)
VALUES ('Mac', 2, 14159, '2020-07-11 20:10:32.813406', 141800194)
ON CONFLICT (user_id, episode_id) WHERE (NOT ((client)::text = 'Web'::text))
DO NOTHING
;
```

Output:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Your index isn't unique

Comment: Ugh, I looked at this for too long it seems. You are absolutely right and now everything works. Thank you! If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.